# How to calculate a ratio between fields during aggregation in Kibana (5.4.0)?

Tags: kibana

I appreciate if I can get help with my issue. I am really stuck with this...

I have a time series event like below.

[image: timeseries events]

From above time series , I am trying to make below histogram aggregation.

[image: histogram aggregation]

My final goal is to draw a chart like below.

[image: double y-axis chart]

I see that histogram aggregation in visualization can generates data points for *score* and *counts* . But I cannot create the ratio between *counts* and *cumulative sum of counts*.

How can I create the ratio and draw a double y-axis chart in Kibana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing tests , this was **not possible** in kibana ui 5.4.0.